# How to make dataTaskWithRequest to be chronological in swift(Xcode 9, swift 4)?

Tags: ios, swift

I have this question for Xcode9 Swift 4. I am trying to fetch some data from some api, and I need to use these data to display. However, since the urlSession is highly asynchronous, I cannot get the data at the right time (most of the time the data is nil). Here is the code.

```
func getUserInfo(){
    let data = user!.Data as? [String : Any] ?? nil
    if let data = data{
        let ID = data["ID"] as? Int ?? nil
        if let ID = ID{
            let jsonUrlString = "SomeString"
            let requestUrl = URL(string: jsonUrlString)
            var request = URLRequest(url: requestUrl!)

            request.httpMethod = "GET"

            request.setValue("SomeKey", forHTTPHeaderField: "AppKey")
            request.setValue(md5("Someinfo"), forHTTPHeaderField: "Sign")

            dataTask = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request){(data, response, err) in

                guard let data = data, err == nil else {                                              // check for fundamental networking err
                    print("error=\(String(describing: err))")
                    return
                }

                if let httpStatus = response as? HTTPURLResponse, httpStatus.statusCode != 200 {
                    // check for http errors
                    print("statusCode should be 200, but is \(httpStatus.statusCode)")
                    print("response = \(String(describing: response))")
                }

                do{
              guard let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options:  .mutableContainers) as? [Any] else{return}
                    var userInfo = userDetail(json: json)
                    let dataDic = userInfo.dataArray as? [String:Any] ?? nil

                    userInfo.ID = dataDic?["ID"] as? Int
                    userInfo.AccountName = dataDic?["AccountName"] as? String
                    userInfo.Avatar = dataDic?["Avatar"] as? String
                } catch let jsonErr{
                    print(jsonErr)
                }

            }
            dataTask?.resume()
            }

        }
    }
```

I am storing the data into variable userInfo, which has properties like ID, Account Name, and Avatar. But when I call the function in another method "configNavigationBar", it cannot initialize userInfo for me.

```
func configNavigationBar(){
    getUserInfo()
    if dataTask?.state == .completed{
    navigationItem.title = userInfo?.AccountName
    navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
    }
}
```

Can anybody help me with the question! I deeply appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about changing title after successful http request? In a callback. You can configure everything except title before receiving data.

```
func configNavigationBar(){
    getUserInfo { accountName in
        self.navigationItem.title = accountName
    }
    navigationItem.setHidesBackButton(true, animated: true)
    navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

func getUserInfo(_ callback: @escaping (String) -> Void) {
    ...
    var userInfo = userDetail(json: json)
    let dataDic = userInfo.dataArray as? [String:Any] ?? nil

    userInfo.ID = dataDic?["ID"] as? Int
    userInfo.AccountName = dataDic?["AccountName"] as? String
    userInfo.Avatar = dataDic?["Avatar"] as? String

    // here's the insertion
    callback(userInfo.AccountName)
    // end of insertion
    ....
}
```

You might also need to wrap ui update into main thread if http request is using background thread.

```
getUserInfo { accountName in
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        self.navigationItem.title = accountName
    }
}
```

Comment: It works! Thank you so much. Btw, do you happen to know any way to add a loading screen to my app? It really helps me a lot.

Comment: @BoNi what do you mean by "loading screen"? UIActivityIndicator?

Comment: Like having a spinning circle, but I think I figured it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to wait until your data has been downloaded.

While download is busy you should decide to show temporary state on your navigation bar.

Then, when download is finished (or fails), you update the navigation bar again.

Comment: Do you know how should I manage to do that? I was struggling to find a way to decide the temporary state.